# Google Sheets Insert Row Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a running parts order list that several people use. I am trying to have the top row be a form so the user enters Qty, Part #, and Notes and presses Enter. I want it to add a row to the top of the sheet below the headers and maintain the table structure so we can filter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. There is no visible effort shown here.

Comment: Hi @ParagJadhav. I am not new to SO. This is as far as I have gotten. I dont really have a clue how to do what I need and could not find anything to even really get started. So I am hoping someone can give me some ideas that might help me get in the right direction and likely have some more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the top row, go to Tools then create form. This will make it easier to input stuff. Also no one can muck up your sheet.

Also I would read what you can post here :) I like to be friendly so I thought I'd put an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). GAS is the easiest way to read/write data in Google Spreadsheet/Docs/Forms.

So as far as I understand from your question, you need to insert a row in Google Spreadsheet below the header directly as soon as the forms.

**Step 1:** Open the spreadsheet using [`openById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

**Step 2:** Get the worksheet in which you want to save your Google Forms data using [`getSheetByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

**Step 3:** Insert row before specified position using [`insertRowBefore(beforePosition)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowbeforebeforeposition)

So final code should look like this.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BZuYFCnN_g9vn5crxbPeYlhUKwH6N3u0uT8LCmm-neM");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Nov-2017");
  sheet.insertRowsBefore(2);
```

The code above will insert only one row below spreadsheet headers. There is an alternative -> [`insertRowsBefore(beforePosition, howMany)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsbeforebeforeposition-howmany) if you want to insert multiple rows at a specified position.

Try this and let me know if you find any difficulties. Hope this is what you're looking for.